# How to insert own activity on the ViewPager?

Tags: android

I want to create ViewPager with this tutorial: 
[ViewPager example](http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-viewpager-example/)

But i don't know how can I use my own activity on First layout or Second layout.

This is function which change layout:

```
private void setTab(){
            _mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener(){

                        @Override
                        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int position) {}
                        @Override
                        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {}
                        @Override
                        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            switch(position){
                            case 0:
                                findViewById(R.id.first_tab).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                findViewById(R.id.second_tab).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                break;

                            case 1:
                                findViewById(R.id.first_tab).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                findViewById(R.id.second_tab).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                    });

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to create ViewPager with this tutorial: ViewPager example

That is not an especially good sample. Please consider using `PagerTitleStrip`, `PagerTabStrip` (both in the Android Support package, along with `ViewPager`) or one of the classes from [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com).

> But i don't know how can I use my own activity on First layout or Second layout.

`ViewPager` does not hold activities. It holds views, optionally managed by fragments. The concept of having activities inside of other activities is not recommended and is officially deprecated.

Comment: Ok, but PagerIndicator required API 13+, right? I want to use my app on the older API versions. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: @KrystianBersztolc: "Ok, but PagerIndicator required API 13+, right?" -- not that I am aware of. "Is there any solution for this?" -- use `PagerTitleStrip` or `PagerTabStrip` if you do not want to use ViewPagerIndicator. See: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/Indicator